# How to run a subquery based on results of a query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 queries i'd like to run.  The idea here is to run a query on the transaction table by the transaction "type".  Based on these results, I want to run another query to see the customers last transaction based on a specific type to see if the service ID was the same.  If it's not the same, I want to flag it as "upgraded"

Here is the initial query that Pulls the results from a transactions table based on a transaction type:

```
Select customerid, serviceid
from Transactions
where (dtcreated > @startdate and dtcreated < @enddate) and (transactiontype = 'Cust Save')
```

The output for this is:

```
Customerid          ServiceID
    1                   11
    2                   21
    3                   21
    4                   11
    5                   12
    6                   11
```

What i'd like to do next is run this query, matching the customerID to see what the customers last charge was:

```
Select serviceID, MAx(dtcreated) as MostRecent
From Transactions
Where (transactiontype = 'Cust Purchase')
Group By serviceID
```

My Final output combining the two queries would be:

```
Customerid          ServiceID          Last Purchase      Upgraded?
    1                   11                  11               No
    2                   21                  11               Yes
    3                   21                  12               Yes
    4                   11                  10               Yes
    5                   12                  12               No
    6                   11                  11               No
```

I thought this might work but it doesn't quite give me what I want.  It returns too many results, so the query is obviously not correct.:

```
Select serviceID, MAx(dtcreated) as MostRecent
From Transactions
WHERE     Where (transactiontype = 'Cust Purchase') AND EXISTS
                          (Select customerid, serviceid
                           from Transactions
                           where (dtcreated > @startdate and dtcreated < @enddate) and (transactiontype = 'Cust Save'))
GROUP BY serviceid
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: this will be run on 2005 and 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the requirements properly you can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to determine which record is the latest per customerID. Then you can JOIN this back to the transactions table to determine if there is a match in ServiceID:

```
SELECT  r.CustomerID,
        t.ServiceID,
        t.dtCreated,
        Upgraded = CASE WHEN t.ServiceID = cp.ServiceID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM    Transactions AS t
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  CustomerID,
                    ServiceID,
                    dtCreated,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY dtCreated DESC)
            FROM    Transactions
            WHERE   transactiontype = 'Cust Purchase'
        ) AS cp
            ON cp.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
            AND cp.RowNumber = 1
WHERE   t.dtcreated > @startdate 
AND     t.dtcreated < @enddate
AND     t.transactiontype = 'Cust Save'
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Only problem is you need to change 'AND transactiontype = 'Cust Purchase' to Where.....

Comment: @Shmewnix - Sorry, that must be the Friday afternoon mentality kicking in. I have made that change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.
Here t1 gives you the max dtcreated per customer;
t2 contains all transactions in the date range given;
t3 gives you the last purchase per customer.

```
select 

t1.customerid,
t3.serviceid as Last_Purchase_ServiceID, 
t1.dtcreated as Last_Purchase_DateCreated, 

t2.ServiceID as Current_Purchase_ServiceID,
t2.dtcreated as Current_Purchase_DateCreated 

from

(
    select customerid, max(dtcreated) as dtcreated
    from
    Transactions
    group by customerid
) 

t1

join 

(

select customerid, serviceid, dtcreated
from Transactions
where (dtcreated > @startdate and dtcreated < @enddate) and (transactiontype = 'Cust Save')

) t2 on t1.customerid = t2.customerid

join 

Transactions t3 on t1.customerid = t3.customerid and t1.dtcreated = t3.dtcreated
```

Comment: This gives me a lot of the same issues.  It lists all of the customers transactions, not just the last.

Comment: What do you need actually? If you want just the last, get rid of t2.

Comment: Or ... do you need the last transaction in that date range for each customer?

Comment: I want ALL of the initial query within the date range.  I only want the LAST transaction of each customer where the transaction type is "Cust Purchase"

Answer (score 0):

Try `OUTER APPLY`:

```
Select t.customerid, t.serviceid, o.MostRecent
from Transactions t
OUTER APPLY (
             Select  MAx(dtcreated) as MostRecent
             From Transactions
             Where transactiontype = 'Cust Purchase' and Customerid = t.Customerid --And ServiceID = t.ServiceID
            ) o
where (t.dtcreated > @startdate and t.dtcreated < @enddate) and (t.transactiontype = 'Cust Save')
```

Comment: This, like below gives me too many results.  There should be 1 result per customer.  I Want all records from the daterange (should be 1 per customerid) and the LAST transaction for each customer id found in the first query.

Comment: @Shmewnix, This will give exact same count of rows as your `initial query that Pulls the results from a transactions table based on a transaction type:`. If it is not what you want try to explain in more details.